# how to change menu title color android java

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-styles, android-navigationview

I need to change the title color of my menu on my drawer navigation activity.

This is part of my `activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/naView"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="@drawable/navbackground"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/grayWhite"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigationheader"
    app:menu="@menu/menu">
```

And this is my `activity_main_drawer.xml`: (this file is inside the menu folder)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/vibrationItem"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_vibration_24"
            android:title="vibration" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/Settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
            android:title="Settings" />
    </group>
    <item android:title="others">
        <menu>
            <item android:title="Logout"
            android:id="@+id/Logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/logout"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

This is what I get from my code, and how you see the "other" is displayed with a different color:
[image: screenshot]

I saw many solutions on StackOverflow but I have not found a good solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The color of the title group is based on color defined by the **`android:textColorSecondary`** item in your app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*"> 
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

You can override the `android:textColorSecondary` color with:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.titleColor"
    ..>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.titleColor" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Ok I admit this is a better solution then mine... so +1 deserved (also you teach me about the light/dark mode XD) #questal'haivintatu ;)

Answer (score 0):

go to your `strings.xml` file and write this:

```
<string name="namestring"><font fgcolor='#YOUR_COLOR'>others</font></string>
```

now go to your `menu.xml` file and change your code to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/vibrationItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_vibration_24"
        android:title="vibration" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
        android:title="Settings" />
</group>
<item android:title="@string/namestring">

    <menu>
        <item android:title="Logout"

        android:id="@+id/Logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/logout"/>
    </menu>

</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: i need to change menu title not menu item can you look at the picture to understand me

Comment: @АхмедРашед edit your question with some code of your project

Comment: @АхмедРашед I Need even the menu.xml where are all the items

Comment: @АхмедРашед put the item inside the group

Comment: you make it clickable just like menu item and i don't won't this i need it to be just a title not item

Comment: @АхмедРашед I found the solution XD, now I will edit my answer

Comment: @АхмедРашед accept the answer, so you avoid other users wasting time reading your question

Comment: I don't think it is a good way to solve it. For example you can't define different colors for light/dark mode unless cloning the strings. Just use the standard attribute in the app theme or override it.